Convert or copy a folder from a git branch with all its history to be a new git branch
I have the following Git Branch folder structure:
- b1
-- f1
-- f2
-- f3

I want to create a new branch b2 based on b1 and folder f2 only, then make changes in f2 and rename the folder from f2 to f2_updated and push only f2_updated without f1 and f3. I want to include the commit history of b1/f2 under b2/f2_update.
How I can do that?
I am thinking to do the following:
>git checkout <b1> -- <f2>
>git switch <b2>
...
make the changes
rename f2 to f2_UPDATED
...
>git push ...

The final structure should look like:
- b1
-- f1
-- f2
-- f3


- b2
-- f2_updated


Make a new branch from a subdirectory of an existing branch:
git update-ref refs/heads/$subdir $(
    git commit-tree -p $existing -m "slice $subdir" $existing:$subdir
)

and everything in $subdir will show up as renames of what they were in the parent.
You can merge any changes back by asking Git to spend some time looking for this kind of thing with git merge -Xsubtree or just tell it with -Xsubtree=$subdir.

Thank you, that is interesting. what is the value of $existing?

@tarekahf whatever commit you're branching off of, main or any other way to spell a commit.

Thank you. The inner command is git commit-tree -p $existing -m "slice $subdir' existing:$subdir", correct? I think there is a missing double-quote in the end.

@tarekahf whoops, yup, fixed typos, sorry 'bout that.

Why not use the command git subtree split? It seems it does the trick and much simpler that two nested commands? Please bear with me, this seems a complex thing for me and I am trying to digest it.

@tarekahf subtree split is a vastly more intrusive operation. This affects nothing else, it's a perfectly normal Git thing to do, and it's about as simple as it's possible to get: make and name a new snapshot of already-existing content.

Great! I am not sure what to use for - p parent. I think you said -p $existing meaning that the last point before starting this new branch was the current existing branch. So $existing can refer the the current branch of f1 which is b1, correct? Does it really matter? If I specify main for $existing what is the difference? How this will affect my decision which parent to use?

existing should be set to whatever branch tip you're branching from, because it's the one with the subdir content you're hoisting to the new branch's root.

It worked! Thank you so much. The $subfolder was converted to a branch and all history was maintained. Is it possible to create a folder in the new branch and attach the commit object to this new folder instead of to the branch directly?

Thank you for the help. I am now stuck as I cannot push the changes to the remote branch since it is requesting the commit I created using git commit-tree to be signed, and the commit is done already. How to fix this issue?

@tarekahf you're going to have to re-do the sequence and sign the commit when you create it. git commit-tree can sign commits for you, it's the -S option.

I researched it, why can't I use git commit -S --amend?

A branch cannot be "based on [a] folder" so the whole question is very mysterious and not far short of totally meaningless. A branch is merely a name for a commit, and every commit contains the state of your entire project, as reflected in the index at the moment the commit is created.
If I may make a guess, it seems that you wish to make a branch that lacks folders f1 and f3. The only way to do that, if you are starting at a development point that has them both, is to make a new branch, get on it, and delete those folders, and git add to make that deletion part of the index. Now the snapshot for the next commit, i.e. the index, will lack folders f1 and f3, as desired. Now make your changes within folder f2, git add them too, and now make your first commit with that new branch as head.
You will see that this has worked by saying git switch b1 and git switch b2 repeatedly; you will see the folders f1 and f3 appear and disappear in your working tree as you switch back and forth.

I understand you concern. This is because this repository was migrated from SVN where this repository has multiple branches and each branch has multiple folder, and each folder is a separate project not related which is different that the projects in other branches and folders. It was a mess.

@tarekahf This sounds more like you are about to slice an existing repository into its individual sub-projects. Have a look at git filter-repo; it's designed for this task.

It might be useful to reckon with the fact that a Subversion "branch" is a very, very different animal from a Git "branch".

You can simply create the branch, check it out, remove the folders you do not want and rename the folder you want.
git branch b2
git checkout b2
yes | rm -R f1
yes | rm -R f3
mv f2 f2_UPDATED

EDIT
Worry was expressed about merging b2 into b1 and potentially removing the folders. For this purpose you can

git checkout b1
copy f1 and f3 into a backup
git merge b2
copy back f1 and f3
git add f1
git add f3
git commit -m added back f1 and f3
git push

This will be needed only once in terms of supporting merging b2 into b1, because b1 is beyond the removal of f1 and f3.
If you want to make changes on f2 in b1 and escalate such changes into b2, then you will need to make sure that any change upon f2 is committed without changes inside f1 and f3 while on b1 so you will be able to cherry-pick commits from b1 into b2 without having f1 and f3 copied back.

Does this mean that before you issue the command git branch b2 if you are on the branch b1 then the history will be maintained? But if the team would merge b2 with main, then it will delete f1 and f3. Them how we can ensure that the deletion will not be remembered?

@tarekahf I have edited my answer to address the concern you have expressed.

Thank you. I think I understand how to do this, but it may not work well for my case because there are large number of folders that need to be excluded so this is not practical.

@tarekahf you can generate a script for them. This operation is a one-time necessity, after it's done, the branches are reliable in their handling of the folders.

I googled how to convert a subfolder to a branch and found out that there is a command to do that which is only two steps. What do you think?

@tarekahf can you share the reference?

See this: https://www.deployhq.com/git/faqs/detatch-subdirectory-git-submodule. This is about moving subfolder to another directory. I want to keep existing one though, but it looks like this is what I want git subtree split. I need

@tarekahf I believe that this approach will work for you if you intend to reuse this folder in multiple repositories and you want a single versioning for it. Your scenario seemed to involve a single repository where some folders should only exist in some branches. I advise you to try out the solution by copying your main repository and perform the steps, see whether checking out different branches from the root folder works as expected. Don't push your experimental changes just yet, see whether it works well. If so, then you can push it and choose this approach as your solution.

I have accepted an answer and it is very much what I want to do. You can check it out. The only think I want to do more is to copy the folder f2 in branch b1 to be a new branch b2_from_f2, create a folder f2_new under this new branch to include the source content of b1:f2, and maintain the commit history. I think I can do that by changing the folder structure in b2_from_f2 and doing another commit/push.
